# GraphView Library "Cannot resolve symbol" redrawAll()

Tags: android, graph

I am using the [GraphView Library](http://www.android-graphview.org//) to render a graph. I have placed a checkbox below the graph so that the user can show / hide the legend in the graph. When the user clicks this button, I need to refresh the GraphView.

I tried redrawAll(), but Android Studio says it "cannot resolve symbol".

Here is the code:

```
    chart = (GraphView) chartView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    // Some code goes here
    chart.redrawAll();
```

What other method is availabe to redraw the graph?

Comment: show your code .did you call `compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'`

Comment: Added code above. Yes, I added compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1' to project dependencies. Everything else is working fine. Anyway, I found out a way to refresh using chart.onDataChanged(true, true); It seems the redrawAll() method has been removed from GraphView. It's not there in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to refresh the chart, using the code below:

```
chart.onDataChange(true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset the data, try using

```
chart.removeAllSeries();
```

Comment: This will delete  all series objects that have been added to the chart. This doesn't answers the question asked by OP.